# Array Fill With Space

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array

```
Array (
[0] => 1500 
[1] => 2000
[2] => - )

Array ( 
[0] => 1 
[1] => 2 
[2] => 3 ) 

Array ( 
[0] => 
[1] => - 
[2] => - )
```

Tried this code but it it does not work for me

```
$default = array_fill(0,3,'-');
$paymentexplode = array_replace($default, explode(",",$CARDNUMBER_PAYMENT_MX));
$explodedeductedfinal = array_replace($default, explode(",",$PAYMENT_AMOUNT_MX));
```

For Outputing the data in td

```
foreach($explodedeductedfinal as $is){
    $bankname = trim($is);

    if (!empty($bankname)) {
        echo   "<td class='center'>$bankname</td>";
    }
}
```

It only give me this series:

```
CODE1|  CODE2  |CODE3
1500    2000      -
1       2         3
-       -
```

It should be this one

```
CODE1|  CODE2  |CODE3
1500    2000      -
1       2         3
-       -         -
```

Comment: why giving me a downvote?

Comment: all you need is an else in the loop for echoing a dash

Comment: Its not working

Comment: can someone help me here?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an empty cell, you still need to output the `<td>` otherwise you get a lopsided table.

```
foreach($explodedeductedfinal as $is){
    $bankname = trim($is);

    echo "<td class='center'>";
    if (!empty($bankname)) {
        echo   $bankname;
    }
    echo "</td>";
}
```